# Android Studio Space Shooter problems

Tags: java, android-studio

Before anything i just want to say i'm a newbie.
I'm currently trying to make a Space Shooter game on android for a class project however i'm more concerned about learning more than anything.

I have a layout, left, right, and middle button(this one for shooting) set on the screen and a space ship(Bitmap) that moves according to the arrow's direction on a X coordinate. However i am unable to come up with a code for the bullet. I need to make it so it gets the X location of the ship but that it doesn't follow afterwards, since right and left don't stop (X++ and X--), and that i can fire in sucession. Also i can spawn the enemies in random X locations however since Android studio is different from unity i don't know how i'm supposed to destroy the game object, i'm thinking of sending it's position off screen but that is not what i'm aiming for. If anyone could help me i'd appreciate it.

```
package com.example.malditosvirus2.spacegame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Random;


public class GameLoop extends SurfaceView {
    private
    Bitmap bmp;
    private Bitmap bmp2;
    public int Ys;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Bitmap imp;
    private Bitmap red;
    private Bitmap lef;
    private Bitmap rig;

    private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;

    // private SpriteAnimation sprite;
    //private SpriteAnimation sprite2;

    public int b;
    public int a;
    public int Xs;
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private GameLoop gameView;
    private Bitmap backGround1;
    private Bitmap backGround2;
    private Bitmap dea;
    private int bg1Y = 0;
    private int bg2Y = 0;
    private int speedScroll = 2;
    private int yLowerLimit;
    private int Ysize;
    private int Xsize;
    private int Xmove;
    private int Ymove;
    boolean right = false;
    boolean left = false;
    boolean shooting = false;
    private boolean start = false;
    private int y=-250;
    private int x;
    private int XB=Xmove;
    private int YB=Ysize;
    private Bitmap bul;





    public GameLoop(Context context) {
        super(context);
        gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);

        holder = getHolder();
        xPos = this.getWidth() / 2;


        //  for (int i = 0; i < tot; i++) {
        //  x[i]=rand.nextInt (1000)+ 100;
        //x[i] = rnd.nextInt(Xsize * 2 - dea.getWidth());
        //Xs = gameView.getWidth() /3;
        // Ys = gameView.getHeight();

        //}

        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                boolean retry = true;

                gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                while (retry) {
                    try {
                        gameLoopThread.join();
                        retry = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                gameLoopThread.start();

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                                       int format, int width,
                                       int height) {

            }


        });


        backGround1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg1);
        backGround2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg1);

        bg1Y = 0;
        bg2Y = (backGround1.getHeight());

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        Xsize = width / 2;
        Xmove = Xsize;
        Ysize = height;
        yLowerLimit = height - 100;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.xwing);
        rig = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.right);
        lef = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.left);
        red = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.redball);
        dea = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.deathstar);
        bul= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bullet);










        //bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cow);
        //sprite = new Sprite(this, bmp);
        //sprite2 = new SpriteAnimation(this, bmp2);





    }



    //criar no modo override OnTouchScreen para cima baixo, utilizar codigo anterior


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (right == false && left == false) {
            Xmove = Xsize - bmp.getWidth() + 110;
        }
        if (right == true) {
            //for (Xmove = 0; Xmove < Xsize * 2 - bmp.getWidth(); Xmove += 10) ;
            Xmove += 20;
            if
                    (Xmove >= Xsize * 2 - bmp.getWidth()) {
                Xmove -= 20;
                Xmove = Xsize * 2 - bmp.getWidth();
            }
        }
        if (left == true) {
            //for (Xmove = 0 - bmp.; Xmove > 0; Xmove -= 10) ;
            Xmove -= 20;
            if (Xmove <= 0) {
                Xmove += 20;
            }
        }
        if (shooting == true) {
            YB -= 20;


            if (shooting == true && right == true) {
                XB--;
            }
            if (shooting == true && left == true) {
                XB++;

                if (start == true) {
                    y += 30;
                }
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                doDrawRunning(canvas);
                //sprite.onDraw(canvas, xPos, yPos);
                canvas.drawBitmap(red, Xsize - 150, Ysize - red.getHeight() - 10, null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(lef, red.getWidth() - 50, Ysize - rig.getHeight() - 10, null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(rig, Xsize * 2 - rig.getWidth() * 2 + 50, Ysize - rig.getHeight() - 10, null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bul, XB, YB, null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, Xmove, Ysize / 2 + 500, null);
//
            }

            //a = xPos + 80;
            // b = yPos + 80;
            //sprite2.Draw(canvas, a, b);
            //
        }
    }
        private void doDrawRunning (Canvas canvas){
            Log.i("MovingBackGround", "doDrawRunning");
            bg1Y += speedScroll;
            bg2Y += speedScroll;

            Log.i("MobindBackGround", "bg1Y:" + bg1Y);
            Log.i("MobindBackGround", "bg2Y:" + bg2Y);

            if (bg1Y > yLowerLimit) {
                bg1Y = bg2Y - backGround1.getHeight();
                Log.i("MovingBackGround", "novo bg1Y:" + bg1Y);
            } else if (bg2Y > yLowerLimit) {
                bg2Y = bg1Y - backGround2.getHeight();
                Log.i("MovingBackGround", "novo bg2Y:" + bg2Y);


            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(backGround1, 0, bg1Y, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(backGround2, 0, bg2Y, null);


        }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad at the moment. You're asking multiple questions and you've provided no code. You're making it difficult for us to help you. You'd be better off asking a single question (i.e. "Why doesn't this bullet move as I'm expecting it to?") with the code you've tried to solve the problem, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Android Studio is not meant for game development. Please use Unity or similar game engines. Eventually try to learn LibGDX if you want to stay in Java field.

Comment: @Michael I'm trying to type the code but the site doesn't allow it, keeps saying to indent it, again sorry i'm still new to this.

Comment: @SocketByte I realized that in the first class we had, however we have no choice in the matter when it comes down to the engine we are using.

Comment: @Michael i've put the code, does this help? My main problem is i'm using the x cordinate of the ship for the location of the bullet, but everytime i go left or right it follows it, what should i do so that the bullet gets the x position of the ship but after i fire it it doesn't follow it's x no longer?